# Why python launcher and IDLE have different path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using MAC OS, I downloaded Python 3.6 from official website and installed it. However for a same code:

`import sys
print(sys.path)`

If I ran it in IDLE, it shows:

[image: IDLE]

If I ran it with Python Launcher, it shows:

[image: Launcher]

They were not in the same directory. I knew Mac had its own Python 2.x.x, but the Python Launcher was downloaded within Python 3 package, it was supposed to have a Python 3's path.

How does this problem happen and is there any way to add directories to my Python Launcher?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have both Python 2 and 3 installed on your system, try invoking Python 3 using:

```
$ python3 your-script.py
```

From your terminal.